# how to evenly space items using item height, number of items, and the middle point

Tags: algorithm

I can't figure out the solution to a simple math problem.
I have an array of 0...n items. I know the mid point of this area and the height of each item. I need to set the yAxis for each item so they're evenly spaced.

```
let group = [..., {id: A, height: 20, yAxis: 0}, {id: B, height: 20, yAxis: 0}, {id: C, height: 20, yAxis: 0}];
let midPoint = 100;
```

I've tried getting the total height of the group/group.length, but how do I set the positions relative to the establised midPoint?

Comment: Do you want the items centered on the y axis marks, or start at the y axis marks?  How would you determine the points if you were using pencil and paper?  What steps must be taken to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your case a value of `0` for the `yAxis` is the mid point.

If this assumptions are true, you could set the `yAxis` for each object using this logic (in pseudocode)

```
totalBetweenSpace = (betweenSpace * (group.size - 1))
maxYAxis = (totalHeight + totalBetweenSpace)  / 2
currentYAxis = maxYAxis
for obj in group
  currentYAxis = currentYAxis - obj.height
  if (obj is not first object in group)
    currentYAxis = currentYAxis - betweenSpace
  obj.yAxis = currentYAxis
```

Where

- `totalHeight` is the sum of all the objects' heights in the group
- `betweenSpace` is the amount of space you want in between each object

Comment: The ```yAxis=0``` is a placeholder for each item. The mid point is the xAxis, and I need the container of the items to be centered relative to the xAxis.

Comment: Okay I think we are saying the same thing.  The value is `0` for the `yAxis` is the middle (positive values are above and negative below).
The logic should work the way you want

Comment: The solution didn't take the midpoint into account, as a result the nodes were positioned too high. It led me to the correct solution which I've posted below if anyone is interested. Thanks! `let baseY = 150;`
      `betweenSpace = 15;`
      `groupHeight = (node.height * group.length);`
      `totalBetweenSpace = betweenSpace * (group.length-1);`
      `maxYAxis = (groupHeight + totalBetweenSpace)/2;`
 `yAxis = nodeIndex * (n.height + betweenSpace) - maxYAxis + baseY + betweenSpace;`